# http to https in EC2 apache2 in AWS

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

I'm trying to have https for a website which is hosted in AWS EC2. I have followed the steps mention in the following link.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04

But still its showing the privacy thing to all user who are visiting the website. How can make the certificate as trusted or how long it will take Amazon to make it a trusted one.

Please help me to solve this. I'm stuck with this for last 2 days. Answers will be appreciated and Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate which you are using is a "Self Signed Certificate (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate)".

In order to get rid of insecure certificate or privacy issues on HTTPS, you need to get your CSR signed from a trusted CA like Comodo, Godaddy etc.

Ref -

https://in.godaddy.com/help/apache-generate-csr-certificate-signing-request-5269
https://help.comodo.com/topic-437-1-843-10843-.html

OR

In case you want free verified SSL certificates, "letsencrypt" is the way to go.
https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: So you are telling I need to pay to Godaddy or Comodo to get the certificate signed?

Comment: Do I want to get signed my certificate from  place I bought my domain? Or I can directly go to godaddy and do it?

Comment: I have one more doubt. As I created a self signed certificate it won't get Secure for all user unless they make it as trust in their system?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements you may wish to use SSL termination on an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) instead.

This involves creating a [**free** AWS certificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request.html) and an [ELB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-getting-started.html). Attach both [your instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-getting-started.html#register-ec2instances) the [certificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-add-or-delete-listeners.html) to the ELB with HTTPS forwarded to port 80 on your instance.

Then just point your DNS name to the ELB. If you're using Route53 then you can just use an [A-record alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-alias.html).

Edit: If you want to automatically direct HTTP to HTTPS you'll need to check the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header in Apache's `.htaccess` file. More information [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/).

Comment: The certificate and instances are attached. I already have an A- alias pointing to my public IP. Do I wanna edit to the load balancer.

Comment: @Shihas please see my edit if you need to configure automatic redirect from HTTP->HTTPS

Comment: I tried by editing the `.htaccess` as mention in link provided above. But still its  Not secure.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Not secure". Are you referring to connection via HTTP (with "Not Secure" in Chrome's header) or you get an error page?

Comment: Yeah when I go to `https://www.xxxx.com` it show that privacy stuff. Then we have to click proceed.

Comment: @Shihas - ok, checklist - **1.** `www.xxxx.com` and `xxxx.com` DNS records are pointing to the **Elastic Load Balancer**, _not_ the EC2 instance? **2.** The certificate you created through Amazon Certificate Manager includes `xxxx.com` and `www.xxxx.com` in the names? **3.** You've removed the self-signed certificate in Apache that you added originally? (reversed the steps you took from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04). **4.** You've created a HTTPS listerer on the ELB and forwarded it to **port 80**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS Certificate Manager to issue free SSL certificate signed by AWS Certificate Authority. However for this to work, you need to use a Load Balancer and attach the certificate to the Load Balancer which will forward the traffic to the EC2 instance.

Comment: Yeah I tried this way [link](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/configure-elb-ssl-aws/), but still it shows No Secure.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pay anyone for a certificate. Just use [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) and their [CertBot ACME client](https://certbot.eff.org). The CertBot automates the task of issuing and renewing certificates.

LetsEncrypt is the leading free SSL certificate authority (CA) and their certs are as good as any paid cert.